# Integrate react native into existing Swift project: 'string' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I try to integrate React Native into my existing iOS app (mixed code ObjC and Swift) according to this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

But whenever I try to compile my project, I get `'string' file not found` (there's also an issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17556 but no solution yet).

Did anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We also recently encountered this while integrating RN through CocoaPods.

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution to this, but as stated by esam091 in that issue you linked, a workaround is to add this postinstall hook in the Podfile.

```
# Podfile

def remove_unused_yoga_headers
filepath = './Pods/Target Support Files/yoga/yoga-umbrella.h'

contents = []

file = File.open(filepath, 'r')
file.each_line do | line |
    contents << line
end
file.close

contents.delete_at(14) # #import "YGNode.h"
contents.delete_at(14) # #import "YGNodePrint.h"
contents.delete_at(14) # #import "Yoga-internal.h"

file = File.open(filepath, 'w') do |f| 
    f.puts(contents)
end
end

post_install do | installer |
 remove_unused_yoga_headers
end
```

This removes the culprit headers.
Still a problem as of RN 0.53